# Completion Handler executed before Request is complete

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch, completionhandler

I have an app that uses `UIImagePickerController` to select an image.  That image is then passed into an API function.  Once that function is complete I pass the result using a delegate to a modal displayed controller with the results.  However, the modal controller is presented before the completion block and my error `AlerViewController` alerts are never called.

The API is run in the background thread, I have set the completion on the main thread (as it updates the UI - presents the modal controller) but it gets called before the completion is fully executed.

Code below;

### API Request

```
func searchImage(with image: UIImage, to viewController: UIViewController, success: @escaping([ViImageResult]?) -> Void) {
        var results = [ViImageResult]()
        let params = ViUploadSearchParams(image: image)
        ViSearch.sharedInstance.uploadSearch(params: params, successHandler: { (data : ViResponseData?) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            if data.result.isEmpty {
                AlertViewController.noResultsFound(viewController: viewController)
                return
            } else {
                if data.hasError {
                    AlertViewController.dataError(viewController: viewController)
                    return
                } else {
                    for response in data.result {
                        results.append(response)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        success(results)
                    }
                }
            }
        }, failureHandler: {
            (error) -> Void in
            AlertViewController.dataError(viewController: viewController)
        })
    }
```

### Controller

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }
            ViSearchSDKService.shared.searchImage(with: selectedImage, to: self) { (results) in
                guard let results = results else { return }
                if self.resultsDelegate != nil {
                    self.resultsDelegate?.recievedResults(recievedResults: results)
                }
            }
            let resultsController = ResultsViewController()
            self.resultsDelegate = resultsController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: resultsController)
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

In the API Request, all my `AlertViewController` functions are called on the main thread and then returns out of the request.  Success block is also called on the main thread.

What am I doing wrong here?...

### Update

I am not quite sure why this works but it does everything I need.  I have moved the API Request into another function outside of

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
```

in my controller.

### New Working Code

```
var selectedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }
            self.searchImage(with: selectedImage)
        }
    }

    func searchImage(with image: UIImage) {
        ViSearchSDKService.shared.searchImage(with: image, to: self) { (results) in
            guard let results = results else { return }
            let resultsController = ResultsViewController()
            self.resultsDelegate = resultsController
            if self.resultsDelegate != nil {
                self.resultsDelegate?.recievedResults(recievedResults: results)
            }
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: resultsController)
            navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not really following your question, but those `guard let results = results else { return }` and `guard let data = data else { return }` lines are paths that can happen without any debug/error handling on them.  Maybe put a `debugPrint` in there and see if it is taking that path ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: My Controller Delegate gets called before the task is fully completed.  I think I need to add a dispatch group for the for loop.

Comment: for response in data.result

Comment: Have you put a break-point in and seen if it even gets to that part of the code?

Comment: Yes.  Everything works fine, except I want to wait until all the items have been appended in the for loop.

Comment: you don't even need the for loop... `results.append(contentsOf: data.results)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126941-append , definitely don't need any access control or wait around it.

Comment: you're right I've changed that, however, my delegate is still called before completion.  I think I have 'success' in the wrong place.

Comment: Lots of unnecessary code and no reproduction path since we don't have all the types, not easy to fix this problem for us

Comment: I am not even sure I understand why we are declaring the `results` and appending??? just pass the `data.results` back in success, no need to "append" them to an empty array.

Comment: I will make an update may have found a solution of running the function outside of didSet selected image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this.

```swift
    var selectedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            // make sure it was not set to nil
            guard let selectedImage = selectedImage else { return }

            // set up your view controller for the response
            let resultsController = ResultsViewController()
            self.resultsDelegate = resultsController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: resultsController)

            // do your search
            ViSearchSDKService.shared.searchImage(with: selectedImage, to: self) { (results) in
                // leave no path without visible side-effect
                guard let results = results else { debugPrint("nil results"); return }

                // now that we have the result, present your results view controller
                navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(navigationController, animated: true) { in

                        // once done presenting, let it know about the results
                        self.resultsDelegate?.recievedResults(recievedResults: results)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working too.  I think the setting of the delegate was in the wrong place.